# Googletalkplugin going haywire

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, google-talk

So I noticed today that Googletalkplugin has created a **TON** of processes.

212 to be exact.

What in the world is happening and how do I solve this?

I am using Windows 7 with Chrome 15.

Answer (score 1):

So far, there is no solution from Google.  The best we can do is a `taskkill`, which in my case, produced three pages of output.

You can use `taskkill /f /IM "googletalkplugin.exe"`

[image]